# schedule the creation of a html page from the server every 30 minutes

Tags: html, asp-classic, schedule

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so point me in the right direction on how to implement it!

Basically I have a panel on my website that's hitting the database and outputting the data to the screen, everytime somebody hits the page. This is a heavy burden on the server and what I would like to do is create a HTML file with the information every 30 minutes and then request this HTML file with an include on the website.

```
<!--#include file="myHTMLpanel.asp"-->
```

By the way, i'm using classic .ASP ;o(

Answer (score 1):

ASP provides a great mechanism for generating web pages, no point in creating your own. Use caching, [like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131054/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032002-1.shtml). Create a scheduled task that hits the server every 30 minutes and breaks the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBScript to write a script that will run your query and write out the HTML page. Schedule it to run every 30 mins via scheduled task.

Comment: Hi JJD, thanks for for the heads up! I actually have the script written and functional. Can you give me an idea of how to setup a scheduled task? I am running on a shared windows webhost. Will this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate a pre-built caching solution on the server rather than writing it manually.

A product such as [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) will make it virtually effortless.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, i'll check it out now!